# Golang + bytea storing in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go, blob, blobstorage

I am struggling with storing `[]byte` data in my Postgresql DB with Golang. I am expecting a certain # of bytes, however, golang adds extra bytes when storing in Postgresql which makes my data invalid. I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

Code is complicated so I simplified it as much as possible and included only the relevant parts. Everything works, query gets executed and stored in db, but the `raw_data` column contains more bytes than it should. The interesting thing is that when I print the `len(raw_data)` right before storing it, the # of bytes is correct. I also printed out the final query right before executing it and executed it manually in my db, and `raw_data` is stored correctly. I don't understand what happens during the query execution in go and why extra bytes are added. I must mention I am using the `pgx` library for posgresql. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx

Code:

```
func escapeString(value *string) string {
    if value != nil {
        return fmt.Sprintf("'%s'", *value)
    } else {
        return "NULL"
    }
}

func constructQuery()(*string, []byte){
    name := "ST_123"
    rawData := getRawData()// this fun returns []byte
    const Query = `INSERT into myTable (name, raw_data) VALUES (%s::text, $1)`

    finalQuery := fmt.Sprintf(Query, escapeString(&name),)
    return &finalQuery, rawData
}

func executeQuery(*string, []byte) {
    _, err := store.dbPool.Exec(context.Background(), *sql, rawData)
}

func processMessage() {
    // parse message logic
   // get appropriate sql query
   var rawData []byte
   var sql *string
   
   sql, rawData := constructQuery()
   // execute query
   executeQuery (sql, rawData)
}
```

Comment: Can't see anything obviously wrong with the code provided. Are you able to reliably duplicate this (i.e. can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))? It would also be beneficial to know the Postgres and pgx versions.

Comment: I will see what I can do about a reproducible example. The `pgx` version is `jackc/pgx/v4 v4.13.0`.

Comment: Storing `[]byte` as `bytea` with `pgx` works out of the box and without the inconsistencies that you've got: https://imgur.com/mHRvsvT.

Comment: Your problem is most likely in this part: *"Code **is complicated** so I simplified it as much as possible..."*, i.e. the problem is in the code that you've omitted for simplicity's sake, which makes it impossible for anyone to suggest, with confidence, a solution for your issue. Also the fact that your as-much-as-possible-simplified example still contains your own "escaping" and the unnecessary overuse of `fmt.Sprintf` and of pointers, hints at more than one possible cause of the problem.